# How to remove extra white background in buttons after using AppCompat Theme?

Tags: java, android, themes, material-design, android-appcompat

TL;DR;

**How to remove the below unwanted white area?**

[image]

I tried to change my theme which extends "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and added my own customization.

After using the theme, all "pop-up" buttons have an extra white background like above screenshot:

1. How to remove those extra white area?
2. What xml attributes are controlling this?

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomAppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Add this in your `styles.xml` and try: `<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån Sorry can you explain more? I added but does not work.

Comment: I think the background is because of this: `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomAppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>` try removing this line and see if it is working as you need.